# How do I move to a new tab in gedit using the keyboard?

Tags: gedit, tabs

If I have multiple tabs open, how do I move from one to another?
(Ubuntu 11.10; gedit 3.2.1)

Comment: Ctrl+N is new tab. Then Alt+Number is for switch tabs. Ctrl+W is for closing the tab.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To move to the previous tab (left): Ctrl + Alt + PageUp
To move to the next tab (right): Ctrl + Alt + PageDown

Full list of shortcuts here: https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html

Comment: Would also love a link to how to customize these shortcuts, so that they comply with standards that every other app uses (i.e., "ctrl + pgup").

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd>. In fact it works with many application that have tabs

Answer (score 6):

You can install [Control Your Tabs plugin](https://github.com/jefferyto/gedit-control-your-tabs), then four shortcuts get added:

> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> /
>     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switch tabs in most
>     recently used order.
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> /
>     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> switch tabs in tabbar order.

<sup>Credit to Trevor Clarke for [posting this on another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/578702/301745)</sup>