# A: What is the hotkey (shortcut) for change current gedit tab?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, gedit

How to change current `gedit` tab without using the mouse?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76082/how-do-i-move-to-a-new-tab-in-gedit-using-the-keyboard

Comment: Well it is already answered at 2 or 3 places here, but I had to search a lot to find the shortcut and even go to Google instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to the next tab to the right > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd> .

For the left < tab change the last key to <kbd>PageUp</kbd>.

---

See [Custom keyboard shortcuts in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223986/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gedit).

Also more `gedit` shortcuts at [help.gnome.org[...]](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en).

Comment: Atleast mark it as answered...

Comment: I'd love to! However I am not allowed until 2 days will pass.