# Is there a hotkey to switch between tabs in Gedit?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit

Is there a hotkey to switch between tabs in Gedit? Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+PageUp are not working. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: ctrl+alt+pageup and ctrl+alt+pagedown seems working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here is a plugin here for gedit to Switch between tabs using Ctrl-Tab / Ctrl-Shift-Tab.
[Control Your Tabs](https://github.com/jefferyto/gedit-control-your-tabs)
There are also similar plugins on the same page.
http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins

Comment: if i download and install the new plugin of gedit from this link 
https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Gedit?action=show&redirect=Gedit
will my default plugin stop working ?

Comment: It shouldn't, it just adds on the feature

Comment: No problem happy to help!

Answer (score 25):

Gedit has this functionality natively, no need for a plugin. Try the following:

- Next tab <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PageDown</kbd>
- Previous tab <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd>

Comment: These shortcuts are inconsistent with virtually all other applications on Linux, the norm is to use `Ctrl`+`PageUp`/`PageDown`

Comment: @nedim: I didn't write Gedit, and I agree completely with you.

Comment: @nedim, I agree. There might be a historical reason Ctrl+PageUp/Down has already a meaning in gedit (Home/End). http://hamwaves.com/gedit/en/#cursor-navigation